# Glitched layers in qgis2threejs map

Tags: qgis, qgis2threejs

I have created a simple, 3D city plan in which only the buildings layer is extruded. The other, just plain layers being *water* and *roads*.

While editing in QGIS everything looks good, but upon launching the qgis2threejs plugin, the water and the roads look ridged. If I export for web and open the project in any browser, the outcome is the same: everything works but these two layers are not displayed properly.

I have tried changing the size of the map, nothing happens; changing the colour of the layers, nothing happens.

Any thoughts on why would this happen and how to prevent it?

[image: dark blue and grey lines, water and roads]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called [z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting) and happens when two planes are directly within each other in 3D space.

Solutions can be either moving the rivers and roads above the terrain by a small offset or turn them into extruded solid objects that protrude above the terrain.